Permanent divisor in highly composite numbers
I was wondering whether it is true that if a particular divisor (be it prime or composite) appears for the first time in the sequence of highly composite numbers (HCNs), would it still be present for all the remaining HCNs in the sequence.
For example, as soon as 2 appears, it seems to be present for all subsequent HCNs,because they all seem to be even from then on (although I don't know any proof for that).
The factor 5 first appears in 60, and stays present for all subsequent HCNs.
So at least for prime factors this seems to be true (although it would be cool to see a proof for that if we want to be certain).
However, when I tried 8 (a composite number), it first appears in 24, however it disappears in 36, then appears again in 48, disappears in 60, comes back for 120, disappears once more in 180, and comes back for 240, 360, 720 and 840, but disappears again for 1260, and after reappearing in 1680, it seems to be present for all subsequent HCNs (up to 2162160 at least, from those listed on Wikipedia). Although I don't know how to prove that it it will always be present from 1680 and on, or whether such a proof exist yet, so if you know one, feel free to enlighten me.
Anyways, now that I know that the first appearance of a (composite?) factor doesn't guarantee that it will stick forever (since the example with 8 above makes it clear that it may in fact disappear and reappear multiple times until staying for longer), the question is:

When is that moment in the sequence of HCNs at which a certain factorappears and stays forever from now on? (i.e. it becomes a permanent factor)How can we prove it?

My first idea came from the observation that some of the first few HCNs are also factorials: 2=2!, 6=3!, 24=4!, 120=5!, 720=6!, 5040=7!. If the pattern continued, this would be the point in which a certain factor MUST be present (or a bit earlier), because all subsequent factorials will necessarily have that factor too.But soon after, I realized that this would guarantee it to be present only in those HCNs that are also factorials, but not necessarily for those in between the factorials :q So although this might be a good way of telling the upper boundary at which a certain factor MUST appear for the first time (although it may appear sooner), it won't tell us much about whether it will stay forever.
Moreover, it seems to be proven that 7! is the highest factorial that is also a HCN.So nope, this approach won't do :(
Any other ideas how this problem can be solved?

What do you mean by "fixed HCN"?

Ah, I see…  So this means that at least for prime factors, their first appearance guarantees permanence?

Well, I'm thinking my argument is a bit glib.  After all, it is not true that the factor of $2$ must exceed the greatest prime...$60=2^2\times 3\times 5$ is an HCN and $2^2<5$.   So, my argument is incomplete (at best).

Yeah, having trouble repairing the argument. I suggest you disregard it. I'll delete my prior comments for now, and will post below if/when I can fix them.

Don't delete them. Even if they are not correct, they still might be a good hint at the right direction, or at least about which approach is incorrect.

Too late.  The false idea was the "observation" that, if $2^n<p_k$ we should replace $p_k$ as a divisor by $2^n$.  This is false as we see by looking at $60=2^2\times 3\times 5$.  Of course $5>2^2$ but if we make the replacement we get $2^4\times 3=48$ which has $(4+1)\times (1+1)=10$ divisors while $60$ has $(2+1)\times (1+1)\times (1+1)$ has $12$.

To be sure, $48$ is itself an HCN but the thrust of the argument fails (or at least it needs to be tightened).

Here is a way to think about how the exponents of primes in HCNs tend to be related.

Anaylyzing using the first $10\ 000$ highly composite numbers , it seems that we can get larger and larger gcd's of all entries by joining into the sequence later and later. This is of course no proof , but it seems that the "permanent divisor" is unbounded.
